# iPhone display screen lights not turning off automatically

Tags: ios, ios5, screen

I have observed that my I run my iPhone application (native) the display lights are not turning off as they usually do in other applications, I have waited for couple of minutes but it wont turn off until I exit my application.
Is there anything which I had messed up with that is not causing the automatic dimming?

Comment: Have you checked your iPhone's settings under General > Auto-Lock.
Make sure it's set to 2 minutes before testing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Are the two lines to enable/disable the dimming of the screen in an iOS app. Double check and see if your app has any of these.

Put this code into application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

Comment: No my app doesnt contain any such code. Do I place this in appdelegate in applicationdidload()?

Comment: yes try putting it applicationDidFinishLaunching and set it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this in your app?
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];`

If so, remove it or set it to `NO`.